# How to write to a continues line in CSV file while maintaining more then one line of code

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to write a continues line in CSV.
Using one line of code it would look like that:

```
outputFile.WriteLine("1111" + "," + "2222" + "," + "3333" + "," + "4444" + "," + "5555" + "," + "6666");
```

well the line is too long for me and I want to split it into two or more lines of code.
I have tried this:

```
outputFile.WriteLine("1111" + "," + "2222" + "," + "3333" + "," + "4444");
outputFile.WriteLine("," + "5555" + "," + "6666");
```

But the end resulte is two lines in the CSV file with an empty cell in the second line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) like this:

```
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
line.Append("1111");
line.Append(",");
line.Append("2222");
//..

outputFile.WriteLine(line.ToString());
```